# PIP error de proxy sin estar conectado a un proxy. Python 3.8.7

Tags: python, pip

recién estoy empezando con Python, quería usar PIP, pero al tratar de instalar colorama, me arroja ciertos errores de conexión/proxy. Mi conexión está funcionando correctamente y no tengo algún proxy que interfiera con las instalaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo seteadas las variables de entorno de HTTP_PROXY ni HTTPS_PROXY.

Estoy usando la versión 3.8.7 de python
La versión de Pip es 20.2.3

Ya probé reiniciando el equipo y desconectándome y volviendo a conectar a la red.

También lo probé con los datos de mi móvil y nada.

Comment: Hola! Comparte el comando y sistema operativos, entre otros detalles de interés, sobre lo que estas usando, así podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: @AmilcarAngeles Estoy usando windows 10 pro, versión 1909, estoy usando pip install colorama.

Answer (score 1):

Ya he encontrado la solución a mi problema, la cual es la siguiente:

1. Abrir Regedit
2. Buscar HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
3. Buscar ProxyEnabled y setearlo a 0, en caso de que este en 1.
4. Borrar otras entradas de proxy, excepto ProxyEnabled

Estos pasos dieron con la solución de mi problema.